# mysql connector with maven: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Driver

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I've a Java EE maven project on a computer which works fine, I've import the project on another computer but when I launch a page I have the following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Driver

The mysql-connector is installed via maven:

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>mysql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
          <version>5.1.30</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't know what to do. Thanks for your help.

Comment: the error says you miss the mysql jdbc driver; you probably need to install that

Comment: Yes but on my another computer I didn't need to install the mysql jdbc driver, maven did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the path where maven is downloading these jars for you added to your classpath? You can add the jar file downloaded by Maven to your eclipse project by selecting the project in eclipse, right click it and go down to properties, select the Java Build Path>>select the Libraries Tab>>Add external jar file and browse for the installed mysql-connector-java.jar file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a little late, but I had this problem even I added mysql dependency in pom.xml. I was using IntelliJ and when I did the following step:

[image]

this problem disappeared.